# How to Read & Store an Instance's Value by looping through an Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, for-loop, instance

**Question:** I am wondering if it is possible to read a value from an instance in an array using a loop and storing or adding them to another variable.

For instance there is a class called `item`

```
class item{
public:
string name;
int value;
};
```

And if there were an array named `inventory` with instances of `item`. (pretend they have values)

```
item inventory[20] = {item.name, item.value};
```

Would it be possible to scroll through that array for a specific value type of an instance? If so is it possible to add that instances value that the for-loop specifically searched for to another variable?

```
    //is it possible to do this?
    for(i = 0; i < 20; ++i){ //not sure if that should be i++ or ++i
      //scan inventory[i] here
      //check for a specific value of an instance such as item.value
      //then add that to a variable 
    }
```

Comment: *not sure if that should be `i++` or `++i`* In that case it doesn't matter, but usual C++ style I see uses `++i` there. Also, for an inventory, don't you want an array of `item`s? (`item inventory[20] = /*blahblahblah*/`)

Comment: What happened when you tried? The array can't be of type int, but otherwise it's just a loop.

Comment: @InternetAussie Makes sense, I will make use of that information :)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The issue is that I don't know how it could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me what your intention is here, but what you are asking is quite simple. Declare a variable to hold the total value:

```
int iTotalValue;
```

Then in your loop do something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
   if (inventory[i].value == iSomeValue) {
      iTotalValue += iSomeValue;
   }
}
```